# Node: How to wait until a file is completed before processing it?

Tags: file, node.js, io

My Problem is that I can not be sure when a file has been successfully written to and the file has been closed. Consider the following case:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var outs = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/file.txt');
var ins = <some input stream>

...
ins.on('data', function(chunk) { out.write(chunk); });
...
ins.on('end', function() {
   outs.end();
   outs.destroySoon();
   fs.stat('/tmp/file.txt', function(err, info) {

      // PROBLEM: Here info.size will not match the actual number of bytes.
      // However if I wait for a few seconds and then call fs.stat the file has been flushed.
   });
});
```

So, how do I force or otherwise ensure that the file has been properly flushed before accessing it? I need to be sure that the file is there and complete, as my code has to spawn an external process to read and process the file.

Comment: Pretty amazing that you can't reliably just dump information into a file via a stream in 2019.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Welcome to AWS! Write a file, and it can take a few seconds before it can be read - even by the very process that wrote it... :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do your file's post-processing in the `writeable stream's` [`close`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close_1) event:

```
outs.on('close', function() {
  <<spawn your process>>
});
```

Also, no need for the `destroySoon` after the `end`, they are [one and the same](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1666).

Comment: Thanks, listening outstream 'close' event seems to do the trick. Didn't know that destroySoon was redundant for files.

Comment: this is actually not working for us. We still have some cases (on SmartOS/Mac and Windows where the close is emitted BEFORE the file content has been flushed)

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue, where `close` fires but the file isn't complete. Ubuntu on WSL (Windows) in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/TomFrost/FlushWritable – I don't know why it's not written into the Writable core but this should do the trick.

Also, there's a discussion addressing this on GitHub https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7348.